# Migrate a custom Magento theme to different server and domain

Tags: magento

I have a custom Magneto theme(Interface) on one store which I would like to migrate to another store which is totally on different server and different domain with slightly different modules.
I have migrated app/design/frontend/CUSTOMTHEME and also skin/Frontend/CUSTOMTHEME

media/catalog/prod/images

But when I upload this theme the store its all broken .

Is it because of local.xml ? Anyways I dont think I can upload local.xml because on this new domain which is a multi store setup we already have a different store working (different local.xml) .

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you want to make sure that you are uploading app/design/frontend/packagename/themename and /skin/frontend/packagement/themename.  Then make sure that this is what is specified in your admin panel, System - Configuration - Design, both Package section and Themes section.

Comment: Also, you may be missing default images used in the old design, so  then you may need to upload images from /skin/frontend/default/default or something similar.

Post your local.xml here if you think that's a problem and post a link to the site if you like

Comment: category pages seems to work , the product pages do not work like they miss add to cart button and entire right hand column blocks etc - while this same pages works fine with my other theme or default theme functionality wise.Also other pages like checkout etc works fine only prob with products pages display with this new theme which has been moved from xamp development ?